# Snapping points to crossroads using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, point

I have some points (370 points) in a layer . These points must snap to crossroad layer . I could'nt find any tools in arcmap to snap points to crossroad layer.

Is there any way to snap these points to the crossroads ?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest running the [Intersect tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000p000000) using the crossroad layer as the sole input, setting the Output type to points. Then take the outputted points layer and run the [Snap tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000007000000) with the points to be snapped as input and the intersect output as snapping features.